# Podio API error "Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain."

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, podio, dynamics-nav

We have integrated Microsoft dynamics NAV 2017 with Podio using the Podio .NET client and when trying to update any item in Podio we get the following error:

"Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain."

What does the error mean and how can we repair it?

We have successfully integrated it and it was working for two weeks before we started getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` flag in `<runtime>` node of Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Server.exe.config file (located in NAV Server folder).

It is described in more detail in the following article:

https://navbis.wordpress.com/2013/12/09/nav-bis-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2013-r2-mapping-issues/